# How to solve this system of equation!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

How to solve this sytem of equation:
$\begin{cases}(\sqrt{a^2+4}+a)(\sqrt{b^2+1}+b)=1\\27a^6+8b=a^3+2\end{cases}$

I tried to analysis equation (1):

$\sqrt{a^2+4}+a=\sqrt{b^2+1}-b\Leftrightarrow a+b=\sqrt{b^2+1}-\sqrt{a^2+4}$
$\Leftrightarrow 4a^2+16b^2+20ab=9$ ...
And then, I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Well... you can let $z=a^3$ and then $27z^2 - z + (8b-2) = 0$. Then use quadratic formula and get $a \equiv a(b)$. Then use back substitution into the first equation.

Comment: I tried to do as you. But I can't continue to do :(

Comment: You can also eliminate b from the second equation and plug its expression in the first equation. This will give you a ... MONSTER ! Are they any restriction for the domains ?

Comment: That way is very complex :( . I will try by maple or wolfram :-ss

Comment: Doing what I suggested, I plotted the first equation as a function of "a" and I only found two solutions close to a = 0.893669 and a = -0.736565.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. But they are very ugly :/ .

Comment: What is the motivation for this problem? Perhaps then we could ascertain why the answer is so "ugly"?

Comment: @abcdxyz. In order to better look at your problem, I defined the euclidian norm of your equations and plotted it in 3D as function od unknownq a and b. Apparently, there are only tow solutions.

Comment: @abcdxyz. I forgot to ask you the key question : are you supposed to solve this problem analytically or numerically ? Also, as Chris K asked, what is the motivation for this problem ?

Comment: Here are all your solutions: [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A((sqrt(a%5E2%20%2B%204))%20%2B%20a)((sqrt(b%5E2%20%2B%201))%20%2B%20b)%3D1%2F%2F%5D%2C%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A27a%5E6%20%2B%208b%20%3D%20a%5E3%20%2B%202%2F%2F%5D%2C%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%2F%2F%5D%2C%5B%2F%2Fmath%3A%2F%2F%5D)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve the first equation for $b$:$$b=-1/2\,{\frac {2\,{a}^{2}+3+2\,\sqrt {{a}^{2}+4}a}{\sqrt {{a}^{2}+4}+a}
}
$$
plugging this in the second equation we get
$${\frac {27\,{a}^{6}\sqrt {{a}^{2}+4}+27\,{a}^{7}-{a}^{3}\sqrt {{a}^{2}
+4}-{a}^{4}-8\,\sqrt {{a}^{2}+4}a-8\,{a}^{2}-2\,\sqrt {{a}^{2}+4}-2\,a
-12}{\sqrt {{a}^{2}+4}+a}}
=0$$
solving this for $\sqrt{a^2+4}$ and squaring again we get this polynomial:

$$729\,{a}^{12}-54\,{a}^{9}-270\,{a}^{7}-107\,{a}^{6}+10\,{a}^{4}+4\,{a}
^{3}+16\,{a}^{2}+20\,a-32
=0$$
with only two real Solutions.
this can be proven by using the Theorem of Sturm.